# Explaining the value of a forecast to the layman

Tags: communication, new-job, colleagues

Im currently working as a data analyst at non-profit. After doing most preliminary work of cleaning the data sets and making them useful for graphing, I find that whatever forecasting methods I use are not quite cared for by the management.

It could be that this is due to lack of organization of their information beforehand. They seem to be willingly oblivious to how certain organizational changes and welfare criteria can impact them in the long run, only caring for where they are now.

My fellow co-staff who don't do such analysis seem to have ideas which are not so statistically sound in terms of future changes and seem wasteful from my current 10 month forecast.

I personally feel that less drastic moves should be taken based on a more complected analysis, however its all jargon to them.

How do I explain in laymen's terms, that forecasts are valuable for policy making and financial decisions?

Comment: Isn't this more belonging to IPS than workplace?

Comment: You seem to be trying to convince management how to do their job, which can't go down well. If you need to present your results in layman's terms, but you can't do that, you should probably work on that and/or you might not be a good fit for that specific job.

Comment: You're asking us how to do your job, not how to navigate the workplace.

Comment: This is not on-topic here at The Workplace, but you might try over at [datascience.se] SE.

Answer (score 2):

If they don't know that they should listen to you, they won't listen to you until you prove to them they can save money.

> [...] forecasts are valuable for policy making and financial decisions

[Prove it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Show,_don%27t_tell).

Make a forecast, send it to them, and a few months down the line when it's obvious they would've [saved / made more] money had they took you seriously, point that out. You may have to rinse and repeat.

Inaccuracies in your report might fuel their confirmation bias, if they've already decided that forecasts are a waste of time. Keep that in mind because you'll have to answer for it.